# How can I quickly groupby a large sparse dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, dask

I have a two-column dataframe that I one hot encode into a sparse dataframe(as it exceeds my systems memory). The problem is when I try to groupby it takes forever.  My goal is to groupby a column so I can get an aggregated view of the number of occurrences, for example, if a user is in two categories they should be displayed once with both categories set to true as opposed to having two rows for the user for each category(which is the current output of get_dummies).

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do along with a few different approaches that get my intended output:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sizeOfRows = 100

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(sizeOfRows, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
one_hot = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['B'], sparse=True)

print("timing different approaches..Hold on to your hats! Just kidding, it's slow, your hat isn't going anywhere!")
%timeit one_hot.groupby('A').max()
%timeit one_hot.groupby('A', sort=False).max()
%timeit one_hot.pivot_table(index='A', aggfunc='max')

#for 100 rows it takes:
1 loop, best of 3: 1.95 s per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 1.94 s per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 1.96 s per loop
```

but my data is ~2M rows so you can imagine how long it takes - if you want to experience the joy of waiting then please set `sizeOfRows` to 1M. I'm wondering if there is a faster way to get the same outcome? I'm not familiar with other approaches.

My end goal is to take this data and process it in tensorflow/keras either by passing the dataframe or via saved .csv file of the resulting groupby Dataframe.

Comment: Have you tested this idea with a smaller dataset?  Are  you sure that ` groupby` frame can be used as input to keras?

Comment: @hpaulj yes I have. Right now I'm using a sklearn pipeline with one hot encoding then pass that to Keras. it's a much smaller dataset than this and works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sparse arrays are killing your performance. Rather than using sparse arrays to save space, you should use [Dask](https://dask.org/) to do this operation in chunks and intelligently spill from CPU to disk, if necessary. If you still need more speed, you should switch to [RAPIDS](https://rapids.ai/) cuDF rather than pandas (cuDF is a GPU DataFrame library).

The following example with two million rows takes about one minute on my 2015 Macbook Air.

First, spin up a cluster.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd
from distributed import Client, LocalCluster, wait

cluster = LocalCluster()
client = Client(cluster)
print(client)
<Client: 'tcp://127.0.0.1:61126' processes=4 threads=4, memory=4.29 GB>
```

Then, create the Dask DataFrame from your example pandas DataFrame. Persist/wait are used only for demo purposes to get a clean %time in the next step. In general, you would skip this step.

```py
sizeOfRows = 2000000

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(sizeOfRows, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=40)
ddf = ddf.persist()
wait(ddf);
```

Finally, do the groupby

```py
%%time
# need to globally know the categories before one hot encoding
ddf = ddf.categorize(columns=["B"])
one_hot = dd.get_dummies(ddf, columns=['B'])
result = one_hot.groupby('A').max().persist() # or to_parquet/to_csv/compute/etc.
wait(result);
CPU times: user 7.23 s, sys: 806 ms, total: 8.04 s
Wall time: 58.4 s
```

Pure pandas will run into memory issues at scale and is slower (on my machine):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sizeOfRows = 2000000

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(sizeOfRows, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
one_hot = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['B'])
%time one_hot.groupby('A').max()
CPU times: user 29.4 s, sys: 42.7 s, total: 1min 12s
Wall time: 1min 36s
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting a error on `ddf = ddf.categorize(columns=["B"]) `  - KeyError: "('get-categories-agg-b7b45311fc7bb403bdc62bd3678b8514', 0)"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

CancelledError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

Comment: You may want to make sure you're using up to date dask and distributed. If this happens mid way through, you may want to try using smaller partitions or reducing the `memory_limit` threshold (this error may be a red herring masking an out of memory error). The dask docs should have more information.

Comment: doing 2M is awesome. I was testing the range..in the example above it's 1k but in my data it's 30k. When I do that I keep getting errors saying it's restarting worker after worker exceeded 95% of memory budget. Is there something I do about that?

Comment: Look into the Dask documentation for details about the memory budget. Think about your data. If you have 2M rows and 30K columns after one hot encoding, holding this in memory will take at least 2e6*3e4*4 bytes if each value is an int32. That's 240GB. Perhaps you could downcast them, further. Either way, you'll need to manage your data and use appropriate hardware to handle it.

Comment: Thank you, I've been playing with the nPartitions and n_workers which seems to be working. The size is a challenge, when it's sparse it's ~100mb df but when it's dense it exceeds my systems memory.  I do have a GPU, do you think it will make a difference? I use/love rapids, so I might experiment with it either way.

Comment: cuDF + Dask groupby aggregations are in general much faster than pandas + Dask (GPUs are very fast). Your dataframe is particularly wide (30,000 columns), so the performance increase may be more modest.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try some multiprocessing?

```
from multiprocessing import  Pool
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sizeOfRows = 100
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(sizeOfRows, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
one_hot = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['B'], sparse=True)

def group_df(df):
    return df.groupby('A').max()

def parallelize_dataframe(df, func, n_cores=4):
    print("spliting...")
    df_split = np.array_split(df, n_cores)
    print("creating pools..")
    pool = Pool(n_cores)
    print("applying function..")
    df = pool.map(func, df_split)
    print("closing....")
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df


parallelize_dataframe(one_hot, group_df, n_cores=2)
```